# Get HTML Head from IE DOM

Tags: c++, html, internet-explorer, dom, head

I know how to obtain the HTML body of a document, using the IHTMLDocument2 interface (by calling the get_body member function.

But how can I get the head? There is no such function in the IHTMLDocument2 interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> htmlDocument;
    CComPtr<IHTMLElementCollection> elementCollection;

    htmlDocument->get_all(&elementCollection);
    for (long i=0;i<numberOfElements;i++)
    {
        _variant_t index = i;
        CComPtr<IHTMLElement> htmlElem;
        CComPtr<IDispatch> htmlElemDisp;
        hResult = elementCollection->item( index,index ,(IDispatch **) &htmlElemDisp );
        if (FAILED(hResult) || (!(htmlElemDisp)))
        {
            continue;
        }
        hResult = htmlElemDisp->QueryInterface( IID_IHTMLElement ,(void **) &htmlElem);
        if (FAILED(hResult) || (!(htmlElem)))
        {
            continue;
        }
        hResult = htmlElem->get_tagName(&buffer);

        if (FAILED(hResult) || (!(buffer)))
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (_wcsicmp(buffer,L"HEAD")==0) 
        { 
         // your code here
        }
}
```

Also, you can use `IHTMLDocument2* htmlDocument` instead of `CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> htmlDocument`.
The main idea is to obtain all elements within your document, iterate them and find the one that has the tagName HEAD.
Hope this helps.